# Themed CSS missing

Tags: 2013, css, theme, 404, brand

I've been having several problems with Themes in 2013 with respect to missing images and resources between environments. They seem to use a theme GUID in paths which isn't the same across environments.

The below CSS reference loads in Dev, but when I deploy my branding solution to Production, it goes missing. Why? This is not CSS I have created or referenced in any Master Page or Page.

How can I ensure all Theme resources are getting loaded no matter the environment it is deployed to?

[image]

I could copy the classes from control15-*****.themedcss to my custom Style.css. but that isn't a great solution

Answer (score 0):

you have to activate the theme on the destination site.

if you enable it just in dev it will not work in prod.

the themed folder is created on-the-fly and the references added to the master page at that same moment.

if you want to use images on your solution, I would recommend having copies of your own